# convert output of postgres query to utf8

Tags: postgresql, utf-8

I used postgresql

in my attachment table the filename_attachmnt column contains character with wrong format .

for example it contains : **ØªÙƒÙ„ÙŠÙ Ø§Ù„Ø²Ù…ÙŠÙ„. Ø§Ø­Ù…Ø¯Ø§Ù„ÙˆØ±Ø¯ÙŠ.pdf**

the correct name it should be this : **تكليف الزميل. احمدالوردي.pdf**

I try without success using this query :

```
select encode(convert(cast(filename_attachmnt as bytea),'UTF8'),'escape') from attachment
```

**updated :**

this is the config of my database :

```
CREATE DATABASE "mobiltyDatabase"
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'SQL_ASCII'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'C'
       LC_CTYPE = 'C'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE "mobiltyDatabase" TO public;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "mobiltyDatabase" TO postgres;
```

Comment: Does DB support UTF-8? Check by running `psql my_database -c 'SHOW SERVER_ENCODING'`

Comment: Does the SQL client you use support _displaying_ those characters?